# What is the runtime of using bit manipulation (XOR and AND) to perform binary addition?

Tags: algorithm, binary, time-complexity, bit-manipulation, big-o

Apparently you can bit manipulation to perform binary addition. This is the Python code for it:

```py
class Solution:
    def addBinary(self, a, b) -> str:
        x, y = int(a, 2), int(b, 2)
        while y:
            answer = x ^ y
            carry = (x & y) << 1
            x, y = answer, carry
        return bin(x)[2:]
```

Basically what is being done is converting the binary strings to integers in base 10 form. Then doing XOR between the two numbers. The XOR is the sum disregarding the carry. Then the carry is calculated separately by ANDing x and y. In the next iteration round the sum of the carry and the previous sum are found, and the carry of this is found the same way, until there is no carry left.

I'm having difficulty explaining what the runtime of the while loop would be. Apparently it's O(max(N,M)) where N represents the number of bits in a, and M is the number of bits in b.

But why? Lost on how to analyze the runtime here.

Comment: ".. to integers in base 10 form" -- note that integers are not in base 10 form. Printing them will by default show you what that integer would look like in base 10, but that's not what an integer *is*, it's just something that humans prefer to look at. Probably most people would not like to look at the raw `ob_digit` array..

Comment: Nothing is converted "_base 10 form_".  You are converting strings to integers. The integers are binary.  If you print their value as decimal, it is the printing function that does the conversion to decimal.

Comment: @Clifford It's the `int` class that does the conversion. The printing function doesn't know anything about that, it just asks the int for a string representation of itself.

Comment: @KellyBundy. I think you missed the point. Base 10 is a presentation not a representation.  The fact remains that there is no conversion to decimal here.

Comment: @Clifford There isn't here, but you/I were talking about *"If you print their value as decimal"*. What do you mean with "presentation" vs "representation"?

Comment: @KellyBundy : Presentation - how a value is displayed/printed/rendered. Representation - how a value is stored in memory, for example a 32bit integer, or a double precision IEEE-754 binary floating point.  The point being that it is not stored as a string of decimal digits.

Comment: @Clifford But *"If you print their value as decimal"*, then it **will** (temporarily) be stored as a string of decimal digits. Like I said, the printing function asks the int for a string representation of itself. And then it prints that string. See the docs for [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) and [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__).

Comment: @KellyBundy  I admit I am in dodgy ground, not being a Python developer, but the fact remains that the OP is mistaken in the assertion that there is a conversion to base 10.

Comment: @Clifford Yes, they're mistaken about that, and it immediately bothered me when I read that and I immediately upvoted Harold's comment and would've upvoted yours as well if it weren't for its second half.

Comment: @KellyBundy.  Understood.

Comment: @Shisui This is [LeetCode - Add Binary](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-binary/description/), right? (For others: The code has LeetCode's distinctive style with a Solution class, OP had asked a LeetCode question the day before, and googling `"answer, carry" "Solution" "addBinary"` from the code gives me 14 results, 13 explicitly about LeetCode and one being this question.)

Comment: Could you please answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's not O(max(N,M)) but O(max(N,M)^2).

Consider `a = '1' * N` and `b = '1'`. You'll loop N times, and each time you'll produce an N-bit number. So that's not linear but quadratic.

None of the numbers are longer than max(N,M)+1 bits, and every operation is linear in the number of bits. And after i iterations, the low i bits of y are zeros, so you loop at most O(max(N,M)) times. Hence O(max(N,M)^2) overall.

You can also see the quadratic time experimentally, here are runtimes (in seconds) for N from 100000 to 400000:

```
100000 0.36107301712036133
200000 1.4743156433105469
400000 5.770820140838623
```

You can see that doubling N roughly quadruples the time, as quadratic complexity does. The test script:

```py
from time import time

class Solution:
    def addBinary(self, a, b) -> str:
        x, y = int(a, 2), int(b, 2)
        while y:
            answer = x ^ y
            carry = (x & y) << 1
            x, y = answer, carry
        return bin(x)[2:]

for N in 100_000, 200_000, 400_000:
    a = '1' * N
    b = '1'
    t = time()
    Solution().addBinary(a, b)
    print(N, time() - t)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZFNTsMwEIXFNqd4K2ojByUVC1QVFhwgG5YIkNM6qqXEjhxHjXfcg003cChOg3-SVp3VN5o34_Gb79_e2YNWp9PPaJv88e_mqzG6g5WdgOx6bWzkLNu1fBjwqtvRSq02GXzsRQO-379IxY0jg2gbBs5QU-TPGKxJqhATg8MTpLLEC9aURawDnjXHg2wF3KUpBFfDURjfOuED7qq048aEoWTCLRzFdovySjA_mkawpD8LjLCjUailIhN9W2_es6zRBpVfDGVRfBZF4bdb4CFB2o37oatyhTtUMa9THtl6DoaR9K_FL0LvL0ZFi2K5N8GGis0tyGFpOsR8j-Uu_w)

Comment: On most modern processors, bit manipulation is O(1) time, even for shifting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083743/is-bit-shifting-o1-or-on

Comment: @Shisui Only for word size ints (e.g., 64 bits), not for arbitrarily large ints like we do have here.